# Inserting data into aerospike using aerospikeTemplate java

Tags: java, spring-data, aerospike

I am trying to insert data into aerospike. To do the same with the AerospikeClient, I wrote:

```
Key key = new Key("test", "myset", "mykey");
        Bin bin = new Bin("shahjahan", "k");
        aerospikeClient.put(new WritePolicy(), key, bin);
```

Now, I want to do the same using AerospikeTemplate. But the insert methods in AerospikeTemplate expect object as parameter, not keys and bins.

```
@Override
    public <T> T insert(T objectToInsert, WritePolicy policy) {
        Assert.notNull(objectToInsert, "Object to insert must not be null!");
        try {
            AerospikeData data = AerospikeData.forWrite(this.namespace);
            converter.write(objectToInsert, data);
            Key key = data.getKey();
            Bin[] bins = data.getBinsAsArray();
            client.put(policy == null ? this.insertPolicy : policy, key, bins);
        }
        catch (AerospikeException o_O) {
            DataAccessException translatedException = exceptionTranslator
                    .translateExceptionIfPossible(o_O);
            throw translatedException == null ? o_O : translatedException;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I want to know that how can I pass keys and values to insert data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your object needs to have an `@Id` annotation to specify the key for the record. All other fields will be stored as bins. Here's an example:

```
public class Product {
   @Id
   private Integer id;
   private String productId;
   private String description;
   private String imageUrl;
   private double price;

   ...
}
```

Then you just call `save()` on the object :

```
productRepository.save(product);
```